# Error within Debug UI: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException after updating Android SDK Tool and ADT

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, android-sdk-tools

Just now I updated Android SDK Tools to 22.6 and then updated ADT to 22.6.
But after that I'm not able to run my android projects in eclipse. I'm getting an error dialog showing this message,

Error within Debug UI: 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Should I update DDMS also?

here is the error window,

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem solved successfully by updating DDMS.

Hope this will be helpful to someone, facing the same problem