# Worked one day, errored out next on Mac: Error within debug UI #appcelerator

Tags: ios, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

This could be related to the problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22345836/error-within-debug-ui-java-lang-reflect-invocationtargetexception-after-updatin), but since this is happening in my iOS build (not Android), and I have cleaned the project and restarted Appcelerator, I don't know why this would occur.

Note - I did not change my dev environment, update appcelerator, or change any certs on my MBA where I'm developing my app. The only thing that I've changed is app code. I thought that I might see bugs or errors, but I'm not trying to debut either, as I'm building and installing via iTunes sync to my ipod Touch w/9.2. The build process and settings have not changed, so I don't even know where to start.

Comment: Could you provide more information on "Error within debug UI" ? You say the only thing that changed is code? If you role back the code to when it last worked does it work again? Also, why don't you build directly to device instead of going through iTunes? Could you see if that makes a difference?

Comment: I had to build to itunes because of the other error I pointed to at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35404482/register-device-fails-in-preferences-studio-platforms-ios-appcelerat/35427856#35427856). Since I could not get Appcelerator to add my device, I had no choice but to go through iTunes. Code rollback did not solve the problem, however, logging in to apple then running again in Appcelerator did make the problem go away. I don't think this is solved, but at least there's a work around. I'll mark this as solved. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work around more than an answer, but for some reason, my device, registered at apple was not being recognized by appcelerator (see note in my comment for related issue). After logging into apple dev center, and going back to appcelerator, the issue appeared to go away. I don't know if this is solved, but the workaround got me in business again.

Comment: Just know that all the button in Studio does (or should do) is open http://developer.apple.com/account/ios/device/deviceCreate.action for you, that's it. So indeed going there yourself until we've fixed that link is a fine "workaround"