# "Register Device" fails in Preferences -> Studio -> Platforms -> iOS #appcelerator

Tags: ios, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-studio

I tried to register a device in appcelerator per the path in the title. When I click "Register Device" it takes me to page that errors out:

"The requested application was not found on this server."

The URL, without the API key is
https://daw.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/DSAuthWeb.woa/wa/login?&appIdKey=&path=%2F%2Faccount%2Findex.action

So if this is not the way to Register a Device in Appcelerator, how do I do it?

Comment: All the research points to some apple intermediate cert reset on 2/14 or 2/15. Nothing worked for several builds - direct to iPod, iTunes sync, and simulator. Now that I came back to try again, after midnight on 2/15, I was able to build on the simulator and i look like it's building for my iTunes sync. I don't understand why it would suddenly works with no changes. Problem wasn't solved, but it's working with no changes.

Comment: To Clarify... are you trying to Register a Device in order to test an App developed in Titanium, to run on the device? If so... This should be done in https://developer.apple.com/ > then Member Center (Log in) > then Certs, Identifier and Profiles > Devices > then Add your device > Re-generate the provisioning Profile while adding that device's UDID selected > use that Provisioning Profile to run the App on device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can register a device at:
https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/device/deviceCreate.action

For me the button in the Appcelerator Studio (after signing in with Apple) lead me to:
https://developer.apple.com/account/overview.action

I've asked for our link to be updated:
https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TISTUD-7993

Comment: Thanks again Fokke. My device was already registered at the apple dev center, but for some reason, simply logging into apple again (followed your link), then logging into appcelerator again seemed to fix the problem. I don't know if the apple intermediate cert caused some caching issue since it's in my keychain, but just the apple dev center intermediate step got me on my way. These detours are quite distracting, but thanks again for your help. I'll mark this work around as solved since you have a ticket in Jira and my work around gets me on my way.